# BeautifulSoup scraper doesn't retrieve any information

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve football squads data from multiple wikipedia pages and put it in a Pandas Data frame. One example of the source is this [link][1], but I want too do this for links between 1930-2018.

The code that I will show used to work in Python 2 and I'm trying to adapt it to Python 3. The information in every page are multiple tables with 7 columns. All of the tables have the same format.

The code used to crash but now is running. The only problem is that it throws an empty .csv file.

Just to put more context I made some specific changes :

Python 2

`path = os.path.join('.cache', hashlib.md5(url).hexdigest() + '.html')`

Python 3

`path = os.path.join('.cache', hashlib.sha256(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() + '.html')`

Python 2

`open(path, 'w') as fd:`

Python 3

`open(path, 'wb') as fd:`

Python 2

`years = range(1930,1939,4) + range(1950,2015,4)`

Python 3: Yes here I also changed the range so I could get World Cup 2018

`years = list(range(1930,1939,4)) + list(range(1950,2019,4))`

This is the whole chunk of code. If somebody can spot where in the world is the problem and give a solution I would be very thankful.

````
import hashlib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

if not os.path.exists('.cache'):
    os.makedirs('.cache')

ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/15612.1.29.41.4'
session = requests.Session()

def get(url):
    '''Return cached lxml tree for url'''
    path = os.path.join('.cache', hashlib.sha256(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() + '.html')
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print(url)
        response = session.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': ua})
        with open(path, 'wb') as fd:
            fd.write(response.text.encode('utf-8'))
    return BeautifulSoup(open(path), 'html.parser')

def squads(url):
    result = []
    soup = get(url)
    year = url[29:33]
    for table in soup.find_all('table','sortable'):
        if "wikitable" not in table['class']:
            country = table.find_previous("span","mw-headline").text
            for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
                cells = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
                cells += [country, td.a.get('title') if td.a else 'none', year]
                result.append(cells)
    return result

years = list(range(1930,1939,4)) + list(range(1950,2019,4))
result = []
for year in years:
    url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+str(year)+"_FIFA_World_Cup_squads"
    result += squads(url)

Final_result = pd.DataFrame(result)
Final_result.to_csv('/Users/home/Downloads/data.csv', index=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')```





  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_squads
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about each team for years 1930-2018 you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}_FIFA_World_Cup_squads"

dfs = []
for year in range(1930, 2019):
    print(year)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(year)).content, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.find_all(
        lambda tag: tag.name == "table"
        and tag.select_one('th:-soup-contains("Pos.")')
    )

    for table in tables:
        for tag in table.select('[style="display:none"]'):
            tag.extract()
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
        df["Year"] = year
        df["Country"] = table.find_previous(["h3", "h2"]).span.text
        dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
...
13   14   FW                    Moussa Konaté       3 April 1993 (aged 25)    28                                       Amiens  2018                 Senegal   10.0
14   15   FW                     Diafra Sakho   24 December 1989 (aged 28)    12                                       Rennes  2018                 Senegal    3.0
15   16   GK                   Khadim N'Diaye       5 April 1985 (aged 33)    26                                       Horoya  2018                 Senegal    0.0
16   17   MF                     Badou Ndiaye    27 October 1990 (aged 27)    20                                   Stoke City  2018                 Senegal    1.0
17   18   FW                     Ismaïla Sarr   25 February 1998 (aged 20)    16                                       Rennes  2018                 Senegal    3.0
18   19   FW                     M'Baye Niang   19 December 1994 (aged 23)     7                                       Torino  2018                 Senegal    0.0
19   20   FW                      Keita Baldé       8 March 1995 (aged 23)    19                                       Monaco  2018                 Senegal    3.0
20   21   DF                   Lamine Gassama    20 October 1989 (aged 28)    36                                   Alanyaspor  2018                 Senegal    0.0
21   22   DF                     Moussa Wagué     4 October 1998 (aged 19)    10                                        Eupen  2018                 Senegal    0.0
22   23   GK                     Alfred Gomis   5 September 1993 (aged 24)     1                                         SPAL  2018                 Senegal    0.0
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @Andrej Kesely Although your code throws me an error that I couldn't find the answer. It refers to `lambda tag: tag.name == "table"` and at the end it says. `"'{}' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time".format(pseudo). NotImplementedError: ':-soup-contains' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time`. Pretty strange because I upgrade Soup and bs4. I am using Pycharm my interpreter is 3.7. Pip has been upgraded.

Comment: @JuanCarlosSaravia Update `bs4` to the latest version. Also check if you have latest `soupsieve`. I have `2.2.1`

Comment: Thank you very much! @AndrejKesely Actually I just upgraded everything even my PyCharm. The code ran perfectly thanks a lot! Now I just have to update my git in PyCharm for the version control and I am done. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just tested, you have no data because "wikitable" class is present in every table
You can replace "not in" by "in":

```
if "wikitable" in table["class"]:
   ...
```

And your BeautifulSoup data will be there

Once you changed this condition, you will have a problem with this list comprehension:

```py
                cells += [country, td.a.get('title') if td.a else 'none', year]
```

This is because td is not defined in this list, not quite sure what is the aim of these lines but you can define tds before and use them after:

```py
tds = tr.find_all('td')
cells += ...
```

In general you can add breakpoints in your code to easily identify where is the problem

Comment: Thanks @mysterymachines It indeed solved me one part. But I am not sure where to put. `tds = tr.find_all('td')`. If I comment `cells += [country, td.a.get('title') if td.a else 'none'` the code gives me the result but it doesn't show the column titles and all the data of the third and fourth columns are missing and the data is all scrambled. I will keep checking this. Any advice will be helpful.